# Terraform: how to ignore "Error: Your query returned no results" for data source "aws_instances"

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm using Terraform 0.14.4 to maintain different AWS accounts. I have one `.tf` file and multiple state files, one for each account.

I use a data source to find all EC2 instances that have a certain tag attached to it:

```
data "aws_instances" "all_instances" {
  instance_tags = {
    Monitoring = "MONITOR"
  }

  instance_state_names = ["running", "pending", "stopped", "stopping"]
}
```

This data source is used to generate a few CloudWatch metrics for certain instances.

I have instances with that tag in all accounts but one. Running `terraform plan` on that account gives me this error:

```
Error: Your query returned no results. Please change your search criteria and try again.
  on main.tf line 6, in data "aws_instances" "all_instances":
   6: data "aws_instances" "all_instances" {
```

I'd like to ignore that the data source doesn't find any instances in this particular account, and go ahead with all the other resources maintained in my script.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: All your accounts must have such instances. Data sources don't return empty results. If they can't find a match, they error out. And you can't ignore that.

Comment: Hm, I feared that answer. I've come up with a work-around using the `count` condition in the data source, querying some variable that helps me identify the account. Not the best solution, as I might launch instances in that particular account in the future. I'll have to update the script then, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from what you mentioned in the comment, one other possibility would be to use [External Data Source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external/latest/docs/data-sources/data_source). So instead of using data source given by aws provider (`aws_instances`) you could implement your own. This way you can program in any logic you want, including handling missing resources.